# Cannot override CORS headers in Slim Framework

Tags: php, cors, slim-3

I am using Slim v3 with the CORS middleware at https://github.com/tuupola/cors-middleware to handle CORS headers. Everything works, however I now need to be able to modify the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header based on who a user is logging in as. I have another middleware that executes after the CORS middleware to do user verification, and I was hoping that from within this middleware I could just add $response  = $response->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $userdomain) and it would keep the rest of the CORS headers set by the previous middleware, but override that one. However, this doesn’t seem to happen. No matter where this middleware executes, the CORS headers are always the ones defined by the CORS middleware.

The current setup looks like this:

```
$app->add(new \Internal\OAuth\Middleware($this->getDBs()));

$app->add(new \Tuupola\Middleware\Cors([
    "origin" => ['*'],
    "methods" => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'OPTIONS', 'DELETE'],
    "headers.allow" => ['', 'Authorization', 'Content-Type', 'Content-Length', 'Origin', 'Accept'],
    "credentials" => true,
    "cache" => 100
]));
```

The \Internal\OAuth\Middleware __invoke looks like this:

```
public function __invoke($req, $res, $next) {
    //do authentication stuff
    $userdomain = 'http://blahblahblah';
    $res = $res->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $userdomain);
    return $next($req, $res);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

`index.php`:

```
<?php

$app = new \Slim\App();

$app->add(new \Internal\OAuth\Middleware());

$app->get('/', function(\Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface $req, \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface $res, $args) {
    $res->getBody()->write(json_encode(['url' => $req->getUri()->__toString(), 'args'=>$args]));
    return $res->withHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
});

$app->run();
```

`src/Internal/OAuth/Middleware.php`

```
<?php

namespace Internal\OAuth;

use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;

class Middleware
{

    /**
     * @param ServerRequestInterface $req
     * @param ResponseInterface $res
     * @param callable $next
     * @return ResponseInterface
     */
    public function __invoke($req, $res, $next) {
        //do authentication stuff
        $options = [
            "origin" => ['http://blahblahblah'],
            "methods" => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'OPTIONS', 'DELETE'],
            "headers.allow" => ['', 'Authorization', 'Content-Type', 'Content-Length', 'Origin', 'Accept'],
            "credentials" => true,
            "cache" => 100
        ];
        $cors = new \Tuupola\Middleware\CorsMiddleware($options);
        $handler = new Handler($res, $next);
        $res = $cors->process($req, $handler);
        return $res;
    }
}
```

`src/Internal/OAuth/Handler.php`

```
<?php

namespace Internal\OAuth;

use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use Psr\Http\Server\RequestHandlerInterface;

class Handler implements RequestHandlerInterface
{

    protected $callable;

    protected $response;

    public function __construct(ResponseInterface $response, callable $callable)
    {
        $this->callable = $callable;
        $this->response = $response;
    }

    public function handle(ServerRequestInterface $request): ResponseInterface
    {
        $handler = $this->callable;
        return $handler($request, $this->response);
    }
}
```

Tests:

1.

```
curl "http://localhost:8088" --request OPTIONS --include --header "Origin: http://disallowed-host" --header "Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT"

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Host: localhost:8088
Date: Tue, 04 Dec 2018 13:19:14 +0700
Connection: close
Content-Length: 0
```

2.

```
curl "http://localhost:8088" --request OPTIONS --include --header "Origin: http://blahblahblah" --header "Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT"

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Host: localhost:8088
Date: Tue, 04 Dec 2018 13:19:04 +0700
Connection: close
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://blahblahblah
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Max-Age: 100
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE
Content-Length: 0
```

Comment: Sorry I took so long to respond, but I had to update wamp and php to get this to work.

Sadly, this does not seem to be working: prior to the "$res = $cors->process($req, $handler);" line, the $res takes the form of a Slim\Http\Response Object, wheras after it is taking the form of a Zend\Diactoros\Response Object, which does not seem to contain the origin domain url.

Comment: I little more study indicates that the original version through Tuupola\Middleware\Cors as in the initial post is located at "[tip:protected][static][callable][callable:Slim\DeferredCallable:private][options:Tuupola\Middleware\Cors:private]" in the Apps object. The version in this post places it at "[tip:protected][static][next][static][callable][callable:Slim\DeferredCallable:private][options:Tuupola\Middleware\Cors:private][origin]" - with an extra next => static layer - this may be where the issue is

Comment: Figured out what was wrong, the authorization code (https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-server based I believe) was clashing - I moved them to separate classes and that solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In the middleware you need to add a header AFTER the handler

```
<?php

namespase \Internal\OAuth;

class Middleware
{
    public function __invoke($req, $res, $next) {
        //do authentication stuff
        $userdomain = 'http://blahblahblah';
        $res = $next($req, $res);
        return $res->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $userdomain);
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be helping, at the very least I can update the Access-Control-Allow-Origin now. More bug hunting to do, but of a different kind. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, I may have been premature with my assumptions here: The header output for the Access-Control-Allow-Origin contains the user domain, but the Cors output seems to retail the original origin command ('*') meaning that when testing as a request from a domain different to the one assigned to the user, it is allowed to go through instead of being blocked.

ie: the origin variable of the options:Tuupola\Middleware\Cors:private object remains '*' instead of becoming 'http://blahblahblah'

Comment: See my next answer